# Firebase Firestore Can not add array in an object that is inside an array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to perform this simple insertion to build up a sample record

[image: Firebase Firestore Adding Record]

I get this as a result:

[image: Unable to save field]

I tried to search this issue and it was mentioned in a similar way here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/193

but I still can not solve this even when building nested arrays indirectly.

If this is not supported, why am I getting the option to add array in the first place.

Any help appreciated.